# Dynamically set a number in a classname depending on the number of elements in a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The thing is a little bit difficult to explain for me, so I'll do my best.
I have a slider, and inside it a each loop returns 3 elements (three products), and I want to set a classname "slider-n" where n is the element number (it should be 1, 2 and 3). I can't, for example, put "product.id" because the products will change and the id's too (actually, the ids are 14, 15, and 16) so I've been wondering what's the best solution for this. There's a photo of the structure [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vHjL.png). Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you share what you have tried so far? Probably it's going to be easier to help you once we know what is the structure of your code

Comment: I've tried putting another loop with an array of numbers and using the ID's but it didn't work. I'll try the answer Genesis Guerrero Martinez gave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `each.with_index` :

```
<% @store_preview.each.with_index do |product, index| %>
  <div class="slide-<%= index %>"
    ...
  </div>
<% end %>
```